# Select records for a day and a day - 1 day

Tags: postgresql

From one table, I want to get the records from one column `position` when the `created_at` = `Today` and when the `created_at` =   created_at - 1.day

```
COALESCE(array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position)) AS position,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN date(pr.created_at) = date(pr.created_at) - interval '1' day THEN array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position) ELSE NULL END) AS y_position
```

Example

```
1. Id: 1 Position: [1, 2] Created_at: 2014-04-10
2. Id: 1 Position: [1, 3] Created_at: 2014-04-09
3. Id: 1 Position: [2, 3] Created_at: 2014-04-08
```

Output:

```
1. id: 1 Position: [1, 2] y_position: [1, 3] Created_at: 2014-04-10
2. id: 1 Position: [1, 3] y_position: [2, 3] Created_at: 2014-04-09
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just guesswork:

```
SELECT t.id, t.position, y.position AS y_position, t.created_at
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   tbl y USING (id)
WHERE  y.created_at = t.created_at - 1;
```

- Basically, you seem to be after a self-join. Using [**table aliases**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) you can join the same table multiple times in one query.
- You can just subtract an `integer` from a [**`date`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html) - assuming it is a `date`, not a `timestamp`. Table definition is missing.
- If you want to include rows where no row from "yesterday" can be found, make that a [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) instead of `JOIN`.
- No idea why you have `array_agg()` or `COALESCE`  in your question. Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

The following will work for SQL Server.  Hopefully you'll be able to translate it to Postgresql.

```
select
    t.id,
    t.position,
    y.position as y_position,
    t.Created_at
from MyData t
inner join MyData y
    on y.id = t.id
    and y.Created_date = DATEADD(day, -1, t.Created_date)
```